# History of 13 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)The first issue of the Siddur by the Hebrew printing press of Amsterdam was Published in 1626.

2) Romanian Jews where barred from the Medical Practice in 1868

3)Empress Maria Theresa expelled all Jews of Bohemia and Moravia in 1744.
·

4) First Jewish censor was appointed by the Russian government to censor Hebrew books in 1798.

5) There where Anti-Jewish riots in Ancona , Italy in 1798.

6)Hermann Goering appointed Reinhard Heydrich head of Jewish Emigration,in 1939.

3)Yahrtzeits

-Moshe Lelover 1850

-Rav Nosson Nata Segal Landau Mechaber of Kerem Nota

-Death of Judah Touro,  whose foundations paid for the completion  of the Bunker Hill monument, which enclosed the Jewish Cemetery in Newport , Rhode Island . also together with Montefiore helped build the first housing complex outside the walls of the old city of Yerushalayim , Mishkenot Shananim.His death was in 1854

*From Matzav.com*